# Nagios command definition files

Tags: linux, python, nagios

Im following the tutorial from this page. 
[Writing Custom Nagios Plugins](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/7706/)

Everything is working fine my only problem is that the first config file your supposed to edit is the command-plugins.cfg file and I cant find the file. I did the following command

```
find / -name "*cfg"
```

and the results showed all my nagios cfg files but command-plugins.cfg was not one of them.

So I continued on with the tutorial and did everything else. Nagios tried to perform my custom service check but this error returned

```
(Return code of 127 is out of bounds - plugin may be missing)
```

So im assuming that the command definition still has to be made but where? Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: latest nagios version? latest nagios-plugins version?

Comment: Yes this is a brand new install I did last week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make changes to any of the `*.cfg` files that Nagios knows about — you do not have to actually have one called `command-plugins.cfg`.  The important thing about a command definition is that it has the right format, e.g.:

```
define command {
    command_name    an_alias_to_the_command
    command_line    /pathto/your_command_script --arg1 --arg2
}
```

Nagios will use one major config file to determine all other files to load.  For me it is `/etc/nagios/nagios.cfg`.  This file contains directives, such as `cfg_file` and `cfg_dir` to load either an individual file, or all `*.cfg` files in a directory.

I prefer to split my commands file based on my own categories, so mine has an entry in it:

```
cfg_dir=/etc/nagios/commands
```

This means I will load all the `*.cfg` files in my `/etc/nagios/commands` directory.

You should look at your equivilent `nagios.cfg` file to determine all the places it will load `*.cfg` files from — you should be able to determine which file to edit or where to create a new file from there.